# How can i see how many files are inside one directory and its subdirectories

Tags: windows-xp

I am using Windows XP and I have MP3 files inside one folder with many sub directories.
I want to know how many files are there. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Right-click the directory and click `Properties`.